# Trying to change "view all" text on my wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I am trying to change the "view all" text on my wordpress website. It cannot be done via the dashboard, so I am looking for the right file to edit on my ftp server. However, I cannot find the file with that text in it. It seems not to be in style.css.

http://test.healthclubone.nl/

Can you help?
Thank you.
Robin

Comment: Do you want to change; the text `MEER INFO` to `View all` or do you want to change the styling(like color, font-family, size, line-height etc)?

Comment: Check the Appearance -> Widgets section. Text must be there somewhere.

Comment: Hi, I want to change the text 'View all' to 'Meer info'. In which file can I find the CSS code? It seems not to be in Style.css. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, you will get the `view all` from widgets created in backend.

By checking source code, it is coming from widget-7.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks.
Indeed I can see widget-7 when checking the element via browser. However, I cannot find widget-7 on the FTP server.. Any idea how to find it?

Comment: you will find it from your Wordpress 's Dashboard : 

`Appearance -> Widgets section`.

Comment: Hi Jenis, thanks for your anwer but it is not in the widget section. It is not a field I can edit. Any other ideas?

Comment: If it is not a thing that can be edited from dashboard then it must be present in your wordpress theme files. Try `Ctrl + F` with in your theme files for `view all` text. Hope you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text by CSS:

```css
.viewall > a::before {
    content: "MEER INFO";
    font-size: 10px;
}
.viewall > a {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
Result:
<span class="viewall"><a href="#">TEST</a></span>
```